# I'm trying to do an 'each do' code that will generate my alt, src and title in the same line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, haml

Hi how do u achieve this one on Ruby HAML, I'm trying to do an 'each do' code that will generate my array collection of alt, src and title in the same line but I ran out of idea on how to do it.

**Please help this is my code.**

```
// Page Settings

- @transition = "data-transition"
- @effect = "sliceDown"

- @slides = [ '1.jpg','2.jpg','3.jpg' ]
- @slide_titles = ['Title_1','Title_2']                     
- @alt_name = ['Alt_Name_1','Alt_Name_2']
```

**This is my each.do code**

```
- @slides.each do |slides|
     %img{:src => slides, :alt => @alt_name, :title => @slide_titles, @transition => @effect}
```

I wanted to make a code that would make it easy for me to paste this tons of images and for future use. I am stuck in here.

**This is the output,**

```
<img title="["Title_1", "Title_2"]" src="1.jpg" data-transition="sliceDown" alt="["Alt_Name_1", "Alt_Name_2"]">
```

**What I expect to have is**

```
<img title="Title_1" src="1.jpg" data-transition="sliceDown" alt="Alt_name_1">
<img title="Title_2" src="2.jpg" data-transition="sliceDown" alt="Alt_name_2">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- @slides.each_with_index do |slide, i|
     %img{:src => slide, :alt => @alt_name[i], :title => @slide_titles[i], @transition => @effect}
```

Your code did not give what you expected because you were using the `@alt_name` array, and others instead of just using the position which you wanted. You actually can see in your output it's an array in there instead of just a string.

I just changed `each` for `each_with_index` so it also gives the index (position) of the current slide, and then we use the index to get the title and alt_name in the same position doing `@alt_name[index]`

Maybe a practical example:

```
alt_name = ['Alt_Name_1','Alt_Name_2']
alt_name[0] #=> 'Alt_Name_1'
alt_name[1] #=> 'Alt_Name_2'
```

Comment: that was quick, thanks!!. can you give me some teaching on how this [i] made this work? :/. Still new to ruby and I want to learn this things. Thanks :D

Comment: Edited my answer. Don't forget to accept it and maybe vote up if it was helpful.